# How can I delete all custom transform orientations?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to update a script I used in 2.79 to delete all custom transform orientations (CTOs).

The new API replaced `bpy.context.scene.transform_orientations` with `bpy.context.scene.transform_orientations_slots`. The problem is, for some reason, this is returning only the active CTO, not a list of the CTOs that I created. I couldn't find a way to return a list of CTOs so I can later iterate through them and delete them.

**Tried:**

Researching the matter, the closest thing I could find is `bpy.ops.transform.select_orientation(orientation="some_CTO_name")`.

However this is not useful in my case, since the argument will only accept a string enum.

Also the info window isn't helping. When I change the Transform Orientation manually, the listener is printing `bpy.context.scene.type = "TO_Name"`. Trying to use this in the console or the script will throw an `AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'type'`.

**The Script:**

Following is the script. If you try it, it will only delete the CTO if it's already active. My question is, how to get the list of the CTOs?

```
import bpy
orient = bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots
views = [area.spaces.active for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
areas = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']

for o in orient:
    if views and areas:
        views[0] = o
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area']= areas[0]
        try:
            bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation(override)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: I decided to put together a Blender Addon based on Iyad Ahmed's script to help out my workflow in Blender and it is working fine. You are all welcome to give it a try. Hope it can be useful for you guys too. It is good for Blender 2.80 and newer versions. The **Custom Transform Orientations Purge** addon can be found at my public GitHub repository at this [link](https://github.com/mmmrqs/cto_purge)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was trying to solve the same problem, came up with this workaround.

If we tried to set `transform_orientation_slots[0].type` to a non existent value, we get this error:

```
TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "" not found in ('GLOBAL', 'LOCAL', 'NORMAL', 'GIMBAL', 'VIEW', 'CURSOR', 'Cub', 'Cube', 'Cube.001', 'Cube.002', 'Cube.003', 'Cube.004', 'Cube.005', 'Cube.006', 'Cube.007', 'Cube.008', 'Cube.009', 'Cube.010', 'Cube.011', 'Cube.012')
```

The idea is to try and set that property, catch the error message, do string manipulation, and have a list of transform orientations.

After that we loop through custom orientations, set the transform orientation to it, and execute `bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation()`, the script seems to be working well,

```
import bpy

try:
    bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = ""
except Exception as inst:
    transforms = str(inst).split("'")[1::2]

transform_list = list(transforms)
for enum_type in transform_list[7:]: # The 7 first orientations are builtins
    bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = enum_type
    bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation()
```

I really hope there's a better solution if anyone has, I tried `bl_rna["type"].enum_items`, but it just returns the default orientations, not the custom ones, perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: This works perfectly, many thanks!

Comment: yes triggering the exception and extracting the list is currently the only way to also get the custom values. It's only possible to directly get the list of the built-in transforms using: `for t in bpy.types.TransformOrientationSlot.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items:
    print("Built-in:", t.name)`

Answer (score 3):

As for Blender 3.6 the script by @iyad-ahmed stopped working because Blender added new builtin orientation `PARENT`.

Previous script was relying that there will be exactly 6 builtins, I've updated the script so that it will get the actual list of builtin transformations so it won't break the next time Blender adds/removes new transformation.

PS there is still no other way to get list of all custom orientations besides parsing exception message and excluding builting.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
transform_slots = context.scene.transform_orientation_slots
builtin_transforms = [i.identifier for i in bpy.types.TransformOrientationSlot.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items]

# hacky (but the only way) to get the all available transforms
try:
    context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = ""
except Exception as inst:
    transforms = str(inst).split("'")[1::2]

for transform in transforms:
    if transform in builtin_transforms:
        continue
    transform_slots[0].type = transform
    bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
orient_slot = bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0]
custom = orient_slot.custom_orientation
custom.matrix
```

reference:
https://blenderartists.org/t/2-80-cheat-sheet-for-updating-add-ons/1148974

Comment: bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0] returns the active transform orientation, I'm looking for a way to get a list of the custom transform orientations, I don't see how your answer relates to my question.

Comment: maybe iterate over slots ?